# Syncing program clock with website clock

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Got a question on how i can create a clock for a program i am writing and then sync it to the clock on this website: [Grand Prix Racing Online](http://www.gpro.net/gb/gpro.asp)

Will be working on .net 4.0 and C#. I know the basics already but i want help with the syncing bit especially. The intention of syncing is to do certain actions on that site at very precise (within 1 second) intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that **any time server should report the same time** (after all, time is globally the same consistently!), it doesn't matter which time server you are targeting.

See [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ntpclient.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Thats an interesting link Philipp! I think i will be implementing that one. Once implemented i will perform certain actions on my target site using the program. The site records these actions and the time they were performed. A few trials and i should get an idea whether the server is synced to global time. If it isnt i will adjust my program clock. This should work, right?

Comment: Depending on your requirements regarding accuracy (is being within 10 seconds ok, or do you need a higher accuracy?) you might have to account for networking latency and compensate for it in your code.

Comment: I need 1 second accuracy actually. Yes i plan to compensate for the network variables by averaging a few requests. To get the 1 second accuracy is the most vital thing. If i cannot acheive that the program would be worthless :(

Answer (score 0):

If Grand Prix Racing Online has Web Service (WS) that exposes time than you will need to call that WS let's say once a day and get time from it and update your program time.  So basically you need some way to get time from that WS.

Comment: I dont think it has a WS. Could i just visit the site and subsequently parse out the current time as displayed? Would that give me precise time as thats the major requirement for me.

Comment: Since Grand Prix Racing Online site doesn't have WS than you can call that site's page scrap the text find the time field and update your clock.  Is it accurate - certainly not.  Also the problem with this approach if page is changed and time is moved your code will break.  What you can do is to find out what time server that site is using, so you might synchronize your time with that server instead of Grand Prix Racing Online site.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, Vlad. I think the second approach of finding the time server the site is using could be the best option. But i dont know how i can find that out. Any pointers?

Comment: You can write them e-mail supportgpro.net and ask about that.  Hope this will help.